# Linux command to print some characters from a long string

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, sed, grep

I have a file called text.txt which contain:

```
id="qwidget_lastsale" class="qwidget-dollar">$2020.22\div
```

I really need to print out the word **2020.22** from that text file.

I used the command:

```
awk '{print $2}' text.txt | grep 2020.22
```

but my output will print:

```
class="qwidget-dollar">$2020.22\dev
```

Which command can I use to print out only 2020.22 from that string?

Comment: If you just want 2020.22, why not `echo 2020.22`?  Since that doesn't make sense, it isn't quite what you want?  What should happen if `2020.22` is not present in the file?  Presumably nothing.  What about if there are multiple lines containing `2020.22`?  Are you going to be upset at seeing `2020x22` since the `.` is a metacharacter to `grep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to extract the dollar value?

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\$)[0-9.]+' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'id="qwidget_lastsale" class="qwidget-dollar">$2020.22\div' | awk '{print gensub(/[^0-9.]+([0-9.]+).*/, "\\1","1", $2)}' 
2020.22
```

In gensub we replace most of $2 with just the numeric component, and then print that using the print statement.